# how to preload an audio in html before showing the content to the user

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page full of css animations and it is important for me to have the music from the beginning. I've used  to call the music. here is my code:

```
<body>
<audio  autoplay>
<source src="./1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="./1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<embed height="50" width="100" src="./1.mp3">
</audio>
</body
```

So how can I preload the music (and the images too) and then show the whole page to the users at once?

Comment: Hands up who likes music on a web site......no one.....at all??

Comment: please don't do this. Many people will simply close your page if it has auto playing music.

Comment: I know that! Actually it is something like an animated postal card with a specific audience (1 person!). So just relax! No harm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create JS preloader and show page only after all content ready

The simplest way is create a preloading div at the top of the page and hide it after your music loaded. Or you can wait not only for music, but for all of the content, how you wish

```
#preloadingDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

$("#preloaderDiv").css("height", window.innerHeight + "px");

$("#music").load(function() {
  $("#preloadingDiv").css("display", "none");
  $("#musicPlayer").get(0).play();
});
```